# capture command line output in vbscript

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript

Got a simple script that executes a command to a server - briefly:

```
//Create shell
set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "cmd.exe"

//send commands
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet IP_ADDRESS"
WshShell.Sendkeys "dir"
```

Server offers feedback which I want to capture. I just need to capture the first line into a variable, and then just print that variable out to confirm.

Can you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the Windows `telnet` client for automation purposes. The `telnet` client that ships with Windows was made for interactive use only.

I'd use [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) (from the [PuTTY suite](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)) in batch mode for this:

```
plink.exe -telnet -batch IP_ADDRESS dir
```

The tool doesn't require installation, so you can simply deploy it alongside your script.

Run it either in a batch file using [`head`/`tail`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), or in a VBScript using the [`Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a) method, so you can [read from StdOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbxxzwb5):

```
addr     = "62.39.x.x"
port     = 24
timeout  = 300 'seconds
timedOut = False

cmdline = "echo ""mute near get"" | plink.exe -telnet -batch " & addr & " -P " & port

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'change working directory to directory containing script and plink executable
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sh.CurrentDirectory = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

'wait until command completes or timeout expires
expiration = DateAdd("s", timeout, Now)
Set cmd = sh.Exec("%COMSPEC% /c " & cmdline)
Do While cmd.Status = 0 And Now < expiration
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
If cmd.Status = 0 Then
  cmd.Terminate
  timedOut = True
End If

WScript.Echo  cmd.StdOut.ReadAll

If cmd.ExitCode <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Command terminated with exit code " & cmd.ExitCode & "."
  WScript.Echo cmd.StdErr.ReadAll
  WScript.Quit 1
ElseIf timedOut Then
  WScript.Echo "Command timed out."
  WScript.Echo cmd.StdErr.ReadAll
  WScript.Quit 2
End If
```

Comment: Another scriptable telnet is Telnet Scripting Tool v.1.0
by Albert Yale

Comment: Thanks for your time - the actual command I need to run is "mute near get" - here is what I entered, but it doesn't appear to pass that to the server:

if you can get me through that, would be grateful..
plink -telnet -batch 62.39.x.x -P 24 "mute near get"

Comment: How exactly does it "not appear to pass that to the server"? What do you get when you manually run the command in a command prompt?

Comment: It appears only to work if I do it this way around:

echo "mute near get" | plink -telnet -batch 62.39.x.x -P 24

It now prints it out as the last line of the telnet output - can you please elaborate on how I can capture this using the exec method? this is my last question.... Thanks in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all your assistance. We're nearly there, but unfortunately it does not come to an end, until I hit CTRL-c. I guess perhaps I might need to send an additional exit command or somehow exit the do while loop another way.

Comment: Can you [`Terminate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk84ffsf) the object (`cmd.Terminate`)?

Comment: That works, when I enter a cmd.Terminate once before and once after the Do While statement! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best method, but worked for me:

Windows telnet command can save the output in client side using -f arguments. Therefore, you could use:

```
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet -f D:\output\telnet.out IP_ADDRESS"
```

and at the end of your script, simply process the content of telnet.out