# using batch redirect the output of a Telnet window in which commands are executed via VB script

Tags: batch-file, redirect, vbscript

I have created a code of VBScript which telnet a server through a port. after successful login it will run some commands, and logout.
A batch file is created which it will create a VBScript file and input all above commands.

I need to save all the output of the commands run on the telnet window, i.e. the output of the VBScript which is executed.

Or is their any other way I can run VBScript separately and save logs.

Here is batch code:

```batch
echo Set cloner = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")>> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.run"cmd">> C:\temp.vbs
echo WScript.Sleep 500>> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys"telnet 192.168.1.1 6000">> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")>> C:\temp.vbs
echo WScript.Sleep 500>> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys"root">> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")>> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys"11111111">> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")>> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys"DISP CONFIG">> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")>> C:\temp.vbs
echo WScript.Sleep 1000>> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys"EXIT">> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")>> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys"EXIT">> C:\temp.vbs
echo cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")>> C:\temp.vbs
temp.vbs
del C:\temp.vbs
exit
```

Comment: Also, [do not use the Windows telnet client for automation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16562375/1630171).

Comment: @Ansgar: i had used plink, but was not able to send commands to server.
by using the methos you provided in the another link. i am getting only this output in log file.

{Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.}

Comment: i finaly can save the Output of the telnet session. 

using **-f c:\log.txt ** 

`echo cloner.SendKeys"telnet -f c:\log.txt  192.168.1.1 6000">> C:\temp.vbs`